# Django deny large requests without nginx/apache

Tags: django

Here is a problem, there are constants in Django (in settings):

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = N1 * (1024**2)
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = N2 * (1024**2)
```

Problem : it DOES NOT prevent of large request. It LOADS into temp directory anyway. After loading, it does not generating TooLargeError until i manually check payload manually.

Is it basically possible to prevent loading large file or at least generate bad response using only Django resouces without any other instruments like nginx/apache?

UPD. There correct answer with comment how to use was provided but somehow deleted.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/tests/file_uploads/uploadhandler.py#L8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Image Upload...Prevent huge file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767840/django-image-upload-prevent-huge-file-uploads)

Comment: if this is a duplicate, than explain me next. I have a view method. What i should do to clean my content? What's the point `forms` and `models` in those questions? What is "self" there (in clean_content)? "request", how/where/to what object it should be applied and written and this will prevent of large request? I didn't understand and for me at least that is not an accepted answer... Accepted answer reccomends to use `apache`. Read the title of my question.

Comment: But you'll need nginx or Apache anyway, so why don't you want to do it through there?

Comment: i want to do it without those, for test servers at localhost - i need apache/nginx and no way to solve in other way?

Comment: @ohlr , your answer was useful, not excelent (sometimes provides connectionerror at sender, but correct response from server), but working one, i just going to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the upload handler is on [Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/tests/file_uploads/uploadhandler.py#L8)

The Documentation how to use it can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers)